# Shrine attachment blocks devise confirmation email sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable, shrine

I'm using Shrine gem to allows user upload their document in devise registration form. There is a strange issue as below:

- If no file is attached to registration form, confirmation email is sent successfully.

[image]

- If user attached any file(cv image) to the form, confirmation email is not sent, it seem that `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions` callback is not called even there is a transaction commit event.

[image]

Comment: It looks like `shrine` gem override `after_commit` (https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/master/lib/shrine/plugins/activerecord.rb), so the method `send_on_create_confirmation_instructions` on `devise` gem which is called follow the  `after_commit` callback, will not be called (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)

Comment: so i guess the solution maybe creating another model for `cv` so the `user` model send confirmation email meanwhile the `cv` model will upload image.

Comment: Thanks @LamPhan seems you are right, it works if I create a model to separate Shrine fields from user model.